# Smooth Scroll with navigation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, smooth-scrolling

Can anyone help me with this Smooth Scroll. I can't seem to find the problem.

I have a nice "facebook"-navigation effect and would make it scroll when I push the li-buttons. But it dosen't work! My head is about to explode and me eyes is melting. Hope someone can help me:)

The nav button is hidden in top right corner.

```
(function() {
    var $body = document.body
        , $menu_trigger = $body.getElementsByClassName('menu-trigger')[0];
if ( typeof $menu_trigger !== 'undefined' ) {
    $menu_trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
        $body.className = ( $body.className == 'menu-active' )? '' : 'menu-active';
    });
}
}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this before your body end tag:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function()
{  
   var the_id = $(this).attr("href");  
   $('html, body').animate(
   {  
      scrollTop:$(the_id).offset().top              
   }, 'slow');  
   return false;  
});
```

Comment: I already have a smooth scroll javascript (see fiddle) It is like the content div destroys the effect of the smooth scroll. When I remove the content div it works perfectly but then the "facebook"-navigation isn't working.

Comment: Can u show me what do u mean by the "facebook navigation"

Comment: It is the swipe-slide navigation from left to right or right to left in facebook (on the mobile). The icon on my code is in the top right corner, and when you push it the slide menu appears from left to rigth. And that works great! But then when pushing the links the smooth scroll dont work.